# How can i add onmouse event if mouse move over an image it will display play/stop/pause buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

And also to make for each button an event click.
If i click the pause button it should switch also the button text between pause and continue and act according to the text once continue and once pause.

This is the html code i have:

At top i'm including the jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.1.0/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

At bottom i'm adding the images:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="carousel-wrapper">
        <img id="shadow" src="img/gui/carousel_shadow.png" />
        <div id="carousel">
            <span id="pixar"><img src="img/large/pixar.jpg" /></span>
            <span id="bugs"><img src="img/large/bugs.jpg" /></span>
            <span id="cars"><img src="img/large/cars.jpg" /></span>
            <span id="incred"><img src="img/large/incred.jpg" /></span>
            <span id="monsters"><img src="img/large/monsters.jpg" /></span>
            <span id="nemo"><img src="img/large/nemo.jpg" /></span>
                        <span id="radar"><img src="img/large/radar002665.png" /></span>
            <span id="rat"><img src="img/large/rat.jpg" /></span>
            <span id="toystory"><img src="img/large/toystory.jpg" /></span>
            <span id="up"><img src="img/large/up.jpg" /></span>
            <span id="walle"><img src="img/large/walle.jpg" /></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And last the javascript code the top of the javascript code where i set if to make it to move(play) nonstop speed and all:

```
$(function() {

    $('#carousel span').append('<img src="img/gui/carousel_glare.png" class="glare" />');
    $('#thumbs a').append('<img src="img/gui/carousel_glare_small.png" class="glare" />');
    $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        circular: false,
        auto: true,
                infinite: true,
        items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: 200,
            height: '56%'
        },
        scroll: {
            fx: 'directscroll'
        }
    });

    $('#thumbs').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        circular: false,
        infinite: false,
        auto: false,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        items: {
            visible: {
                min: 2,
                max: 6
            },
            width: 150,
            height: '66%'
        }
    });

    $('#thumbs a').click(function() {
        $('#carousel').trigger('slideTo', '#' + this.href.split('#').pop() );
        $('#thumbs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });

});
```

The mouse when i move it over any of the images should display the play/stop/pause buttons.

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle link ?

Comment: Alex yes here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/5hrn1nop/ the big images is where i wanted to add the buttons. The small images i didn't fix the links but they are not the issue now. What i did is if you put them ouse on the big images the animation pause. But what i wanted to do is that when i put the mouse on the big image/s it will show nice text PAUSED and also to show nicely buttons like stop play and arrows to move forward and backward keft and right. For now i just used the jquery in the javascript part.

Comment: I just added to the scroll section: pauseOnHover: true,
                        duration: 500 so now when you mvoe the mouse over the big image it will pause. But i want now to add text/graphics-text and also buttons/text-like-buttons that if you click on it it will do something. Like it will show for example: Play if you click on the Play text it will do something.

Comment: For example this is what i added to the html now. Inside style tags: <style>.container {
    background: rgb(170, 187, 97); /* Fallback */
    background: rgba(170, 187, 97, 0.5);
}</style> and then in the bottom for the test:  <div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>  something like this. Now i see on the big image this text. But how do i make that the text will be show only when i move the mouse over the image to pause it ? Not just moving the mouse over it but when it's pausing i need to connect it somehow to the pauseonhover in the scroll section in the javascript file code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question has more to do with the plugin. You should check the documentation of [carouFredSel](http://docs.dev7studios.com/jquery-plugins/caroufredsel-advanced), there you can find functions that could be called after and before clicking buttons. This might help